# pandas groupby and shift but inside each block

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, shift

I have a dataframe which then I groupby:

```
ID   week   sale 
A     1     1
A     2     4
A     3     10
B     1     7
B     2     2.3
B     3     4.4
```

I would like to apply shift to get sale for previous week but just stay in the same ID-block. Desired would be:

```
ID   week   sale   sale-shift
A     1     1      nan
A     2     4      1
A     3     10     4
B     1     7      nan
B     2     2.3    7
B     3     4.4    2.3
```

If I use the shift:

```
df['sale-shift']=df['sale'].shift(-1)
```

it doesnt take into account the groupby on ID. I'd like to perform for each ID (in my case customer).

Thank you!

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').sale.shift()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""ID,week,sale
A,1,1
A,2,4
A,3,10
B,1,7
B,2,2.3
B,3,4.4""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")
df['sale-shift'] = df.groupby('ID')['sale'].shift(-1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! As I had done already the groupby, I didnt know that I have to do once more before shift to stay in each group.

Comment: You are welcome.  Feel free to accept responses that directly answer your question.  Or, comment/edit otherwise.  Cheers!